# Change the bounds of a summation formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

[image]

I'm currently reading my notes and this appeared and I tried making the left side change into the right side but it's not working. I know you're supposed to use a change in lower bound and use the summation identity but I still can't get n(n-1)/2 appear. Isn't the identity of summation j = n(n+1)/2?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't arrive at the answer, i'm having major problem with what to sub in when I change the lower bound form 2 to 1

Comment: Basically, I change it from j = 2 to j=1 and plug in the identity and I got 3(n(n+1)/2) - 1+n+1

Comment: I minus one because I changed the lower bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your result once again.

$$\begin{align}3 \sum_{j=2}^n j - (n-1) & = 3 \left(\sum_{j=1}^n j - 1\right) - n + 1 \\ & = \frac{3n(n+1)}{2} - 3 - n + 1 \\ & = \frac{3n(n+1)}{2} - n - 2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are having difficulty showing that the LHS equals the RHS because it *does not*.

Using the 'change of indexation' what we can show is that your LHS equals:

$$\begin{align}3\sum_{j=2}^n j -(n-1) & = 3\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1) -(n-1) \\[1ex] & = 3\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+ 3(n-1)-(n-1) \\[1ex] & = 3\frac{(n-1)n}{2} \color{red}{+2} n-2 \\[1ex] & = 3\frac{n(n\color{red}{+}1)}{2}-n-2
\end{align}$$

Which *does not* equal your RHS.

Comment: How come your answer is completely different from PTDS?

Comment: It isn't. @user3718584  Our answers are the same because, $\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}+2n = \frac{3n(n+1)}{2}-n$.  We just took a different path.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that :(

Comment: Yeah, I was beginning to get suspicious after 1 hour or so, but it was from my professor's lecture slide so I ended up not doubting it...

Answer (score -1):

Use something like $$\sum_{j=27}^\infty a_j\;=\;\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{j+26}$$.